# Getting wrong coordinates converting UTM to lon/lat with Proj

Tags: python, pyproj

I have tried many ways to convert UTM to lon/lat, and getting always the same weird result.

Getting UTM and lon/lat for a point using GoogleEarth:

```
from pyproj import Proj

lon = -40.729124
lat = -20.967705

z = 24
l = 'k'
posx = 320235.13
posy = 7680455.66

myProj = Proj("+proj=utm +zone=24K, +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")

clon, clat = myProj(posx, posy, inverse=True)

print(clon, clat)
```

I get...

```
-43.534213641680765 69.17434868536577
```

What do I missing?

Comment: Maybe you should try "24" instead of "24k", or you may add the -I (ie. upper i) flag instead.

Comment: By running your code line-by-line in Python window I can see `pyproj.exceptions.CRSError: Invalid projection: +proj=utm +zone=24K, +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: Error 1027 (Invalid value for an argument): utm: Invalid value for zone)`. Fix the syntax as advised in the answer by @sutan.

Comment: I copied the code from a working notebook! I removed the 'k' and got the same result. By the way, I installed the 'UTM' package and got the right result. But I wonder what could be the issue here using Proj!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `"+proj=utm +zone=24 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs "`. use [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/32724) to identify the appropriate proj4 input, look at the bottom of the page.

another alternative is just use epsg code which is easier like this,

`Proj('EPSG:32724')`

---

alternatively using `geopandas`

```py
from geopandas import GeoSeries
from shapely.geometry import Point

posx = 320235.13
posy = 7680455.66

# utm 24s is equivalent to epsg:32724
lon, lat = GeoSeries([Point(posx, posy)], crs='EPSG:32724').to_crs('epsg:4326')[0].coords[0] 

print(lon, lat)

# this prints -20.967705012999282 -40.729123995168585
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. Works nicely too!

Comment: good to know it works Carlos. if I may ask, please click the "check" on the answer to confirm that the answers work (: @CarlosAugustoFranaSchettini It'd be really helpful. thanks!

Comment: Checked. It works when I removed '+ellps=WGS84' from the 'Proj'. I copy the code from https://ocefpaf.github.io/python4oceanographers/blog/2013/12/16/utm/, and there it seems it works well!

Answer (score 4):

After trying your code I could get an error:

> pyproj.exceptions.CRSError: Invalid projection: +proj=utm +zone=24K,
> +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: Error 1027 (Invalid value for an
> argument): utm: Invalid value for zone)

Which tells explicitly : *"Invalid value for zone"*.

However, as soon as you erase `K,` it can be validated.

Hereafter, it is suggested to work with the [`Transformer`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html#transformer) class, that takes into account datum shifts.

```py
from pyproj import CRS
from pyproj import Transformer

posx, posy = 320235.13, 7680455.66

from_crs = CRS.from_proj4("+proj=utm +zone=24 +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
to_crs = CRS.from_epsg(4326)

proj = Transformer.from_crs(from_crs, to_crs, always_xy=True)
coordinates = proj.transform(posx, posy)

print(coordinates) #(-40.729123995168585, -20.967705012999282)
```

Comment: This is a useful reference to add to your answer: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#proj-not-a-generic-latitude-longitude-to-projection-converter

Comment: Thank you. It is curious that I don't get any error message... The code runs and gives me the wrong result, with our without 'k'. Your suggested code worked perfectly!